# Proof of w obeys Chi-square distribution with r degrees of freedom

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

In my econometrics book, it has a footnote saying:

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be an $m$ dimensional random vector, if $\mathbf{x} \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is nonsingular, then $ (\mathbf{x} - \mu)'\Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \mu) \sim \chi^2(m)$ with $m$ degrees of freedom.

How to prove this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct and should be: $$(\mathbf x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf x-\mu)\sim\chi^2(m)$$

You can write $\mathbf x-\mu=A\mathbf u$ where $\mathbf u$ has **standard** normal distribution and $\Sigma=AA^T$.

Then:  $$(\mathbf x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf x-\mu)=\mathbf u^T\mathbf u$$

Here $\mathbf u^T\mathbf u$ has chi-square distribution.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I found I missed that -1, and corrected it. I also have a question, what's the intuition behind the idea of writing $x-\mu=Au$ where $u$ has standard normal distribution...I couldn't really comprehend that directly..Thanks!

Comment: Standardizing. If $X$ is a random variable $\sim Normal(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $U:=(X-\mu)/\sigma\sim Normal(0,1)$ and we can write $X=\sigma U+\mu$. Then things can be calculated by means of $U$ (no annoying parameters) and the results can be projected on $X$. That is a very handsome route and also is available by random vectors, Covariance matrix $\Sigma$ can be written as $AA^T$ and then $A\mathbf u$ (where $\mathbf u$ has standard distribution) has covariance $AA^T=\Sigma$. If $\Sigma$ is non-singular then so is $A$ and the equality $\mathbf x-\mu=A\mathbf u$ can be turned around.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: I have another question, when simplifying $(Au)^T\Sigma^{-1}(Au)$, I got to $u^TA^T\Sigma^{-1}Au$, how did you derive $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A = I$? Thanks again!

Comment: $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A=A^T(A^T)^{-1}A^{-1}A=I$ on base of general rule $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Comment: Oh...geez...sorry my brain is totally stuck now and way too stupid not to see that...thanks, and this is a brilliant proof!!!