# Finding the distribution of $\|X-\mu \|_\Sigma^2$ with $X \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared

> Let $\Sigma$ be positive definite and symmetric and let $\| x \|_\Sigma := \sqrt{x^t\Sigma^{-1}x}$ be the Mahalanobis norm. Let further $X \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ be a $p-$variat normally distributed random vector. Find the distribution of $\| X-\mu \|_\Sigma^2$.

I do not kow how I could do that. Could you help me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3127503/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2808041/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\lVert X-\mu \rVert^2_\Sigma&= (X-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (X-\mu)\\
&= Z^T Z
\end{align*}
Where $Z=\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}} (X-\mu)\sim\mathcal N (0,I)$.

Hence the distribution is a $\chi$-squared distribution with $p$ degrees of freedom.