# Showing square sum of regression is chi square distribution with p degree of freedom, where p is number of coeeficient.

Tags: statistics

b is the least square estimator of the general linear model $Y=X{\beta}$ where X is a n x p design matrix and $ Y\in R^p, {\beta}\in R^n$.

I want to prove blue part below. I worked some as you can find in the image I attached. But I found $Var(Xb-X{\beta})$ part is wrong since X doesn't have inverse.

Is there any other way I can show $Var(Xb-X{\beta})={\sigma}^2 I$? If I cannot is there any other way to prove this problem?

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU5gV.jpg)

Comment: It would be better if you type out the image. Do you know the distribution of $b$, its mean vector and dispersion matrix?

Comment: This follows from the fact that if $Z\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is positive-definite, then $(Z-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(Z-\mu)\sim \chi^2_p$. You can find a proof here and in its linked posts: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3442471/321264.